# Create a list everytime I encounter a certain word in a str

Tags: string, python-3.x, list, spyder

My problem is that I wanted write a code that did that:

```
    input => str_of_words = '<post>30blueyellow<post>2skyearth<post>5summerwinter'
    output => post30 = ["blue","yellow"]
              post2 = ["sky","earth"]
              post5 = ["summer", "winter"]
```

At first I thought I could do something like

```
     if "<post>" in str_of_words:
         occurrence = str_of_words.count("<post>")
         #and from there I had no idea how to continue coding it
```

So I feel like I could ask if anyone knew some tricks to do that

Comment: Plenty of string tricks are available in Python, but there is a big difference between splitting a string by delimiter `<post>` (which we do with `str.split("<post>")`) and trying to figure out what two words are in `30blueyellow` with no discernible rule to split them by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `nltk` module:

```
import re
import nltk
nltk.download('words')
from nltk.corpus import words

def split(a):
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if a[:i] in words.words() and a[i:] in words.words():
            return [a[:i],a[i:]]


str_of_words = '<post>30blueyellow<post>2skyearth<post>5summerwinter'

post = {i:split(j) for i,j in dict(re.findall(r'post>(\d+)(\w+)',str_of_words)).items()}

post['30']
 ['blue', 'yellow']

post['5']
 ['summer', 'winter']

post['2']
 ['sky', 'earth']
```

Answer (score 0):

this might get you started:

```
import re

str_of_words = '<post>30blueyellow<post>2skyearth<post>5summerwinter'

posts = {}
lst = str_of_words.split('<post>')
for item in lst:
    match = re.match('(\d+)(\D+)', item)
    if not match:
        continue
    posts[int(match.group(1))] = match.group(2)

print(posts)
```

it prints:

```
{30: 'blueyellow', 2: 'skyearth', 5: 'summerwinter'}
```

so `posts[30] = 'blueyellow'`.

the [`re` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) is very helpful when it comes to separating numbers (`\d`) from non-numbers (`\D`).

i don't know according to what rules you would like to be able to split the words. do you have a list of words that could appear?

Comment: Consider every word after "<posts>+any_number" should be given to the last post it appeared. The way you showed me is actually really good, even my prof told me to use re but I wanted to do it without re :/ 
Ty for the answer tho I guess I have to learn that library